# What would you call a drinker of non-alcohol beverages in Russian?

Tags: глаголы, существительные, словообразование

A noun derived from the verb “to drink” is a “drinker”. Following this analogy, how would I derive a noun from Russian verb «пить»? Would that be «пьец», «питьец», «пьюн»?

I know that there are words such as «пьющий», «пьяница», «выпивоха», but they all have a connotation of an alcoholic. What would be a noun that can describe a person who drinks a non-alcoholic beverage in general?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133852/discussion-on-question-by-wintermute-what-would-you-call-a-drinker-of-non-alcoho).

Comment: but we don't have such term in English as well, I mean, nobody says - heavy juice drinker (or does anybody?)

Comment: @shabunc: why not? "5 facts every juice drinker should know". Even in Russian, _носитель штанов_ is comprehensible, as we all know from the lyrics of the relevant song. If the verb in question were _носить_, then _носитель_ would be the answer.

Comment: @shabunc: You can be an anything-drinker, but by default, a *drinker* per se drinks alcohol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I understand it, you are looking for an [agent noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun) (*имя деятеля*) formed from the word *пить*.

I think I can say with confidence that modern Russian lacks such a word.

In Russian, there is no catch-all, universal suffix for agent nouns, similar to the English "-er". Russian uses a plethora of suffixes which work with some words and don't work with the others. The same verb can use multiple suffixes to form agent nouns, which can be synonyms like *косец/косарь*; define different aspects of the agent noun: *бегун* "runner" / *беглец* "fugitive, a person on the run"; and even be arbitrarily assigned to differentiate between related meanings: *страховщик* "insurer" / *страхователь* "policyholder".

Verbs can drop and acquire suffixes over time: *игрец* and *игратель* "player" were used in the past, but not anymore.

Russian does have idiomatic, unbound agent nouns for such basic actions as *есть (едок)*, like in [*Едоки картофеля*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) "The Potato Eaters", *ходить (ходок)*, like in *спортивный ходок* "a racewalker", *любить (любитель)* "lover" etc. Unlike bound agent nouns, which are tied to a specific meaning of the word, these nouns can be used with all, or at least most of the complements the original verb can have. You can't call a person who wears pants **носитель штанов*, but you can call a meat lover *любитель мяса*.

In the past, Russian did have agent nouns formed from the word *пить*, like *питун, питух, питок*. From what I can tell, they were bound, and they all meant "drunkard". The word *питух* was in mainstream use till the end of the XIX century and meant "a person who could hold their liquor".

Modern Russian doesn't have any standalone agent nouns for the word *пить* at all, even bound. Russian does have the words *кровопийца* "bloodsucker" and *чаепийца* "tea drinker", but *-пийца* can't be used in isolation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133851/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-).

Answer (score 2):

While the word пьющий has alcoholic connotations, they are exaggerated by the OP. It's a fairly neutral word, a participle of the verb пить, literally meaning "the drinking one".

If we want a term totally devoid of any alcoholic connotation, we can use compound words like кровопийца, кровосос, молокосос.
But this is not a universal rule, as -пийца has negative connotation and -сос means "-sucker" rather than "-drinker" (implying sucking from another organism or body, so one can be blood-sucker, milk-sucker or semen-sucker but not tea-sucker).

The word пьющий can also produce compounds such as водопьющий or чаепьющий.

Comment: I would note that "водопьющий" and "чаепьющий" are nonce words.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a word specifically derived from the word *пить*, then probably the closest you can get without the "alcoholic" connotation is the word [*пиющий*](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=semx&morph1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=semx&morph2=). This word is an archaic form of the word *пьющий*, which is only used in religious texts.

*И от грозного слова «прокляты» содрогаются ядущие и **пиющие**. [П. И. Мельников-Печерский. В лесах. Книга вторая (1871-1874)]*

Comment: Автору вопроса зачем-то необходимо именно существительное. Да и слово нигде не используется де-факто сто лет в обед как именно таковое и немедленно будет ассоциировано с "пьющими". :> Или, на крайняк, - с "вопиющими". В пустыне :> Или поющими. В терновнике :>

Comment: @Пилум yes I overlooked that the asker wants a noun. He did however list *пьющий* as an example, so I think he might still find the word *пиющий* useful. Although it's a participle, it can be nominalized.

Answer (score 0):

"Потребитель"

Общеупотребительное слово, включающее в себя пьющих, едящих, смотрящих и т.п. Я думаю, вполне приемлемый для языкового контекста вариант.

Answer (score -2):

*"Would that be «пьец», «питьец», «пьюн»?"*

Это бессмысленные наборы букв. В любом случае ни одно из производных от "пьянство" и "пить" тут не подходит, а тем более несуществующие.
[*Пьец, трец и на дуде игрец...*](https://youtu.be/LUoX3lWEIoE) :>

*"how would I derive a noun from Russian verb «пить» except as пьяница?"*

Никак. Именно от "пить". На мой взгляд, все такие варианты нелепы и непонятны. :>

---

Я бы назвал его - [**молокосос**](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D0%BC/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81) :> Существующее слово. Согласно буквальному смыслу, а не общепринятому стереотипу. :> Вспомнилась сцена из ["Горбуна" с Маре](https://youtu.be/dYtmQdOlKmI?t=40), 1959, там, где в трактире с кувшином молока вместо вина... И что потом последовало... :>

Или лимонадосос. Несуществующее слово.

Кокасос. :>

Спрайтосос.

Да. Это **-сос** тут походит. :>

Да, это будет грубо-иронично. :> От слова "сосать".

[**Водохлёб**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%B1) тоже можно. Это тоже пренебрежительно.
Можно образовать и производные - спрайтохлёб... От "хлебать".

---

А если вы хотите нейтральное - используйте слово [**"трезвенник"**.](https://slovarozhegova.ru/word.php?wordid=32197) Существующее слово.Однако оно показывает, что он не пьет алкоголь (см. "трезвость"), но не говорит о чем-то ином. :> [*"Непьющий".*](https://youtu.be/14W-A8c4jxQ)

*"Безалкогольное пиво - первый шаг к резиновой женщине".* Известный афоризм. Так что можно назвать и "резиновый мужик", в шутку. :> В контексте, конечно.

Если вы хотите подчеркнуть именно фанатическое пристрастие к этим напиткам - ну... *кокофан, спрайтофан*... :> Фанатик "спрайта"...
**-фан.**

Также можно образовать от **-ман.** От "мания".
**[Кофеман](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD)** - существующее слово.

Спрайтоман, кокоман (прямо как "наркоман", могут спутать с кокаинистом :>)...

---

*Спрайтолюб.*

Лимонадолюб.

***-люб*** тоже подходит и это будет более нейтрально. Любитель "спрайта".

Comment: +1 for "Трезвенник". This should be the 1st suggestion option for a single word meaning non-alcohol-drinker in Russian.

Comment: In biology, there is a special term for "stable" – it is called "dead". Любой язык развивается и обрастает новыми словами и терминами. Своим вопросом я захотел поднять то, почему в английском мы можем получить существительное, приставив суффикс "-er" к глаголу: to write -> a writer; to walk -> a walker; to paint -> a painter; to drink -> a drinker. Спрашивается, почему я не могу сделать то же самое в русском языке?